# Traefik Rancher new install can't access dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, traefik, rancher

I have a new traefik, metallb install and I'm struggling to access the traefik dashboard. I believe I have the correct ingress routes and I'm trying to access via a local ip:8000/dashboard but it seems to be just hanging. See below the helm for the ingress route and the service. Going to any other route on the same IP returns a 404, which I would expect.

```
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: traefik
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: '2024-01-27T18:36:44Z'
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik-default
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
    helm.sh/chart: traefik-26.0.0
  managedFields:
    - apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
            f:helm.sh/chart: {}
        f:spec:
          .: {}
          f:entryPoints: {}
          f:routes: {}
      manager: helm
      operation: Update
      time: '2024-01-27T18:36:44Z'
  name: traefik-dashboard
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: '629725'
  uid: 7634801b-dcaf-4052-9149-6800f0ec192c
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - traefik
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: PathPrefix(`/dashboard`) || PathPrefix(`/api`)
      services:
        - kind: TraefikService
          name: api@internal
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: traefik-6f79c9bff5-ckfpn
  annotations:
    cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: da09e3dc01d0de9fdc06517dd29effe963d41ba5413f97dc12e83c51a3e418b1
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.42.1.75/32
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.42.1.75/32
    prometheus.io/path: /metrics
    prometheus.io/port: '9100'
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    #  key: string
  creationTimestamp: '2024-01-27T18:26:16Z'
  generateName: traefik-6f79c9bff5-
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik-traefik
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
    helm.sh/chart: traefik-26.0.0
    pod-template-hash: 6f79c9bff5
    #  key: string
  namespace: traefik
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: ReplicaSet
      name: traefik-6f79c9bff5
      uid: 18af1103-198a-4e58-8960-61f0967fde3d
#    - apiVersion: string
#      blockOwnerDeletion: boolean
#      controller: boolean
#      kind: string
#      name: string
#      uid: string
  resourceVersion: '625722'
  uid: a07d7f2b-145c-44bd-9db7-fbeb68ff826c
  fields:
    - traefik-6f79c9bff5-ckfpn
    - 1/1
    - Running
    - '0'
    - 3s
    - 10.42.1.75
    - k8s-worker
    - <none>
    - <none>
spec:
  containers:
    - args:
        - '--global.checknewversion'
        - '--global.sendanonymoususage'
        - '--entrypoints.metrics.address=:9100/tcp'
        - '--entrypoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp'
        - '--entrypoints.web.address=:8000/tcp'
        - '--entrypoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp'
        - '--api.dashboard=true'
        - '--ping=true'
        - '--metrics.prometheus=true'
        - '--metrics.prometheus.entrypoint=metrics'
        - '--providers.kubernetescrd'
        - '--providers.kubernetesingress'
        - '--api.insecure=true'
      env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      image: docker.io/traefik:v2.10.6
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        httpGet:
          path: /ping
          port: 9000
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 2
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 2
      name: traefik
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9100
          name: metrics
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9000
          name: traefik
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: web
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: websecure
          protocol: TCP
      readinessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 1
        httpGet:
          path: /ping
          port: 9000
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 2
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 2
      securityContext:
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        capabilities:
          drop:
            - ALL
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: data
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
          name: kube-api-access-kx97z
          readOnly: true
      _init: false
      __active: true
      resources: {}
  volumes:
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: tmp
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: kube-api-access-kx97z
      projected:
        defaultMode: 420
        sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              expirationSeconds: 3607
              path: token
          - configMap:
              items:
                - key: ca.crt
                  path: ca.crt
              name: kube-root-ca.crt
          - downwardAPI:
              items:
                - fieldRef:
                    apiVersion: v1
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
                  path: namespace
#    - awsElasticBlockStore:
#        fsType: string
#        partition: int
#        readOnly: boolean
#        volumeID: string
#      azureDisk:
#        cachingMode: string
#        diskName: string
#        diskURI: string
#        fsType: string
#        kind: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#      azureFile:
#        readOnly: boolean
#        secretName: string
#        shareName: string
#      cephfs:
#        monitors:
#          - string
#        path: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        secretFile: string
#        secretRef:
#          name: string
#        user: string
#      cinder:
#        fsType: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        secretRef:
#          name: string
#        volumeID: string
#      configMap:
#        defaultMode: int
#        items:
#          - key: string
#            mode: int
#            path: string
#        name: string
#        optional: boolean
#      csi:
#        driver: string
#        fsType: string
#        nodePublishSecretRef:
#          name: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        volumeAttributes:  key: string
#      downwardAPI:
#        defaultMode: int
#        items:
#          - fieldRef:
#              apiVersion: string
#              fieldPath: string
#            mode: int
#            path: string
#            resourceFieldRef:
#              containerName: string
#              divisor: string
#              resource: string
#      emptyDir:
#        medium: string
#        sizeLimit: string
#      ephemeral:
#        volumeClaimTemplate:
#          metadata:
#            annotations:  key: string
#            creationTimestamp: string
#            deletionGracePeriodSeconds: int
#            deletionTimestamp: string
#            finalizers:
#              - string
#            generateName: string
#            generation: int
#            labels:  key: string
#            managedFields:
#              - apiVersion: string
#                fieldsType: string
#                fieldsV1: io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.FieldsV1
#                manager: string
#                operation: string
#                subresource: string
#                time: string
#            name: string
#            namespace: string
#            ownerReferences:
#              - apiVersion: string
#                blockOwnerDeletion: boolean
#                controller: boolean
#                kind: string
#                name: string
#                uid: string
#            resourceVersion: string
#            selfLink: string
#            uid: string
#          spec:
#            accessModes:
#              - string
#            dataSource:
#              apiGroup: string
#              kind: string
#              name: string
#            dataSourceRef:
#              apiGroup: string
#              kind: string
#              name: string
#              namespace: string
#            resources:
#              claims:
#                - name: string
#              limits:  key: string
#              requests:  key: string
#            selector:
#              matchExpressions:
#                - key: string
#                  operator: string
#                  values:
#                    - string
#              matchLabels:  key: string
#            storageClassName: string
#            volumeMode: string
#            volumeName: string
#      fc:
#        fsType: string
#        lun: int
#        readOnly: boolean
#        targetWWNs:
#          - string
#        wwids:
#          - string
#      flexVolume:
#        driver: string
#        fsType: string
#        options:  key: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        secretRef:
#          name: string
#      flocker:
#        datasetName: string
#        datasetUUID: string
#      gcePersistentDisk:
#        fsType: string
#        partition: int
#        pdName: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#      gitRepo:
#        directory: string
#        repository: string
#        revision: string
#      glusterfs:
#        endpoints: string
#        path: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#      hostPath:
#        type: string
#        path: string
#      iscsi:
#        chapAuthDiscovery: boolean
#        chapAuthSession: boolean
#        fsType: string
#        initiatorName: string
#        iqn: string
#        iscsiInterface: string
#        lun: int
#        portals:
#          - string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        secretRef:
#          name: string
#        targetPortal: string
#      name: string
#      nfs:
#        path: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        server: string
#      persistentVolumeClaim:
#        claimName: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#      photonPersistentDisk:
#        fsType: string
#        pdID: string
#      portworxVolume:
#        fsType: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        volumeID: string
#      projected:
#        defaultMode: int
#        sources:
#          - configMap:
#              items:
#                - key: string
#                  mode: int
#                  path: string
#              name: string
#              optional: boolean
#            downwardAPI:
#              items:
#                - fieldRef:
#                    apiVersion: string
#                    fieldPath: string
#                  mode: int
#                  path: string
#                  resourceFieldRef:
#                    containerName: string
#                    divisor: string
#                    resource: string
#            secret:
#              items:
#                - key: string
#                  mode: int
#                  path: string
#              name: string
#              optional: boolean
#            serviceAccountToken:
#              audience: string
#              expirationSeconds: int
#              path: string
#      quobyte:
#        group: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        registry: string
#        tenant: string
#        user: string
#        volume: string
#      rbd:
#        fsType: string
#        image: string
#        keyring: string
#        monitors:
#          - string
#        pool: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        secretRef:
#          name: string
#        user: string
#      scaleIO:
#        fsType: string
#        gateway: string
#        protectionDomain: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        secretRef:
#          name: string
#        sslEnabled: boolean
#        storageMode: string
#        storagePool: string
#        system: string
#        volumeName: string
#      secret:
#        defaultMode: int
#        items:
#          - key: string
#            mode: int
#            path: string
#        optional: boolean
#        secretName: string
#      storageos:
#        fsType: string
#        readOnly: boolean
#        secretRef:
#          name: string
#        volumeName: string
#        volumeNamespace: string
#      vsphereVolume:
#        fsType: string
#        storagePolicyID: string
#        storagePolicyName: string
#        volumePath: string
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - &ref_0
          args:
            - '--global.checknewversion'
            - '--global.sendanonymoususage'
            - '--entrypoints.metrics.address=:9100/tcp'
            - '--entrypoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp'
            - '--entrypoints.web.address=:8000/tcp'
            - '--entrypoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp'
            - '--api.dashboard=true'
            - '--ping=true'
            - '--metrics.prometheus=true'
            - '--metrics.prometheus.entrypoint=metrics'
            - '--providers.kubernetescrd'
            - '--providers.kubernetesingress'
            - '--api.insecure=true'
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          image: docker.io/traefik:v2.10.6
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          name: traefik
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9100
              name: metrics
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 9000
              name: traefik
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: web
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8443
              name: websecure
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 1
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: data
            - mountPath: /tmp
              name: tmp
            - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
              name: kube-api-access-kx97z
              readOnly: true
          _init: false
          __active: true
          resources: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      enableServiceLinks: true
      nodeName: k8s-worker
      preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
      priority: 0
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: &ref_1
        fsGroupChangePolicy: OnRootMismatch
        runAsGroup: 65532
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 65532
      serviceAccount: traefik
      serviceAccountName: traefik
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      tolerations:
        - &ref_2
          effect: NoExecute
          key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
          operator: Exists
          tolerationSeconds: 300
        - &ref_3
          effect: NoExecute
          key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
          operator: Exists
          tolerationSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - &ref_4
          name: data
          emptyDir: {}
        - &ref_5
          name: tmp
          emptyDir: {}
        - &ref_6
          name: kube-api-access-kx97z
          projected:
            defaultMode: 420
            sources:
              - serviceAccountToken:
                  expirationSeconds: 3607
                  path: token
              - configMap:
                  items:
                    - key: ca.crt
                      path: ca.crt
                  name: kube-root-ca.crt
              - downwardAPI:
                  items:
                    - fieldRef:
                        apiVersion: v1
                        fieldPath: metadata.namespace
                      path: namespace
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - *ref_0
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          enableServiceLinks: true
          nodeName: k8s-worker
          preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
          priority: 0
          restartPolicy: Always
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: *ref_1
          serviceAccount: traefik
          serviceAccountName: traefik
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
          tolerations:
            - *ref_2
            - *ref_3
          volumes:
            - *ref_4
            - *ref_5
            - *ref_6
        metadata:
          annotations: &ref_7
            cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: da09e3dc01d0de9fdc06517dd29effe963d41ba5413f97dc12e83c51a3e418b1
            cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.42.1.75/32
            cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.42.1.75/32
            prometheus.io/path: /metrics
            prometheus.io/port: '9100'
            prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
          creationTimestamp: '2024-01-27T18:26:16Z'
          fields:
            - traefik-6f79c9bff5-ckfpn
            - 1/1
            - Running
            - '0'
            - 3s
            - 10.42.1.75
            - k8s-worker
            - <none>
            - <none>
          generateName: traefik-6f79c9bff5-
          labels: &ref_8
            app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik-traefik
            app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
            app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
            helm.sh/chart: traefik-26.0.0
            pod-template-hash: 6f79c9bff5
          managedFields:
            - &ref_9
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldsType: FieldsV1
              fieldsV1:
                f:metadata:
                  f:annotations:
                    f:cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: {}
                    f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: {}
                    f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: {}
              manager: calico
              operation: Update
              subresource: status
              time: '2024-01-27T18:26:16Z'
            - &ref_10
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldsType: FieldsV1
              fieldsV1:
                f:metadata:
                  f:annotations:
                    .: {}
                    f:prometheus.io/path: {}
                    f:prometheus.io/port: {}
                    f:prometheus.io/scrape: {}
                  f:labels:
                    .: {}
                    f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
                    f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
                    f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
                    f:helm.sh/chart: {}
                    f:pod-template-hash: {}
                  f:ownerReferences:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"uid":"18af1103-198a-4e58-8960-61f0967fde3d"}: {}
                  f:generateName: {}
                f:spec:
                  f:containers:
                    k:{"name":"traefik"}:
                      f:env:
                        k:{"name":"POD_NAME"}:
                          f:valueFrom:
                            .: {}
                            f:fieldRef: {}
                          .: {}
                          f:name: {}
                        k:{"name":"POD_NAMESPACE"}:
                          f:valueFrom:
                            .: {}
                            f:fieldRef: {}
                          .: {}
                          f:name: {}
                        .: {}
                      f:livenessProbe:
                        f:httpGet:
                          .: {}
                          f:path: {}
                          f:port: {}
                          f:scheme: {}
                        .: {}
                        f:failureThreshold: {}
                        f:initialDelaySeconds: {}
                        f:periodSeconds: {}
                        f:successThreshold: {}
                        f:timeoutSeconds: {}
                      f:ports:
                        k:{"containerPort":8000,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:containerPort: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:protocol: {}
                        k:{"containerPort":8443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:containerPort: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:protocol: {}
                        k:{"containerPort":9000,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:containerPort: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:protocol: {}
                        k:{"containerPort":9100,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:containerPort: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:protocol: {}
                        .: {}
                      f:readinessProbe:
                        f:httpGet:
                          .: {}
                          f:path: {}
                          f:port: {}
                          f:scheme: {}
                        .: {}
                        f:failureThreshold: {}
                        f:initialDelaySeconds: {}
                        f:periodSeconds: {}
                        f:successThreshold: {}
                        f:timeoutSeconds: {}
                      f:securityContext:
                        f:capabilities:
                          .: {}
                          f:drop: {}
                        .: {}
                        f:allowPrivilegeEscalation: {}
                        f:readOnlyRootFilesystem: {}
                      f:volumeMounts:
                        k:{"mountPath":"/data"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:mountPath: {}
                          f:name: {}
                        k:{"mountPath":"/tmp"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:mountPath: {}
                          f:name: {}
                        .: {}
                      .: {}
                      f:args: {}
                      f:image: {}
                      f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:resources: {}
                      f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                      f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                  f:securityContext:
                    .: {}
                    f:fsGroupChangePolicy: {}
                    f:runAsGroup: {}
                    f:runAsNonRoot: {}
                    f:runAsUser: {}
                  f:volumes:
                    k:{"name":"data"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:emptyDir: {}
                      f:name: {}
                    k:{"name":"tmp"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:emptyDir: {}
                      f:name: {}
                    .: {}
                  f:dnsPolicy: {}
                  f:enableServiceLinks: {}
                  f:restartPolicy: {}
                  f:schedulerName: {}
                  f:serviceAccount: {}
                  f:serviceAccountName: {}
                  f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
              manager: kube-controller-manager
              operation: Update
              time: '2024-01-27T18:26:16Z'
            - &ref_11
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldsType: FieldsV1
              fieldsV1:
                f:status:
                  f:conditions:
                    k:{"type":"ContainersReady"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:lastProbeTime: {}
                      f:lastTransitionTime: {}
                      f:status: {}
                      f:type: {}
                    k:{"type":"Initialized"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:lastProbeTime: {}
                      f:lastTransitionTime: {}
                      f:status: {}
                      f:type: {}
                    k:{"type":"Ready"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:lastProbeTime: {}
                      f:lastTransitionTime: {}
                      f:status: {}
                      f:type: {}
                  f:podIPs:
                    k:{"ip":"10.42.1.75"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:ip: {}
                    .: {}
                  f:containerStatuses: {}
                  f:hostIP: {}
                  f:phase: {}
                  f:podIP: {}
                  f:startTime: {}
              manager: kubelet
              operation: Update
              subresource: status
              time: '2024-01-27T18:26:19Z'
          name: traefik-6f79c9bff5-ckfpn
          namespace: traefik
          ownerReferences:
            - &ref_12
              apiVersion: apps/v1
              blockOwnerDeletion: true
              controller: true
              kind: ReplicaSet
              name: traefik-6f79c9bff5
              uid: 18af1103-198a-4e58-8960-61f0967fde3d
          relationships:
            - &ref_13
              toId: traefik/traefik
              toType: serviceaccount
              rel: uses
              state: active
              message: Resource is current
            - &ref_14
              toId: traefik/kube-root-ca.crt
              toType: configmap
              rel: uses
              state: active
              message: Resource is always ready
            - &ref_15
              fromId: traefik/traefik-6f79c9bff5
              fromType: apps.replicaset
              rel: owner
              state: in-progress
              message: 'Available: 0/1'
              transitioning: true
          resourceVersion: '625722'
          state: &ref_16
            error: false
            message: ''
            name: running
            transitioning: false
          uid: a07d7f2b-145c-44bd-9db7-fbeb68ff826c
    metadata:
      annotations: *ref_7
      creationTimestamp: '2024-01-27T18:26:16Z'
      fields:
        - traefik-6f79c9bff5-ckfpn
        - 1/1
        - Running
        - '0'
        - 3s
        - 10.42.1.75
        - k8s-worker
        - <none>
        - <none>
      generateName: traefik-6f79c9bff5-
      labels: *ref_8
      managedFields:
        - *ref_9
        - *ref_10
        - *ref_11
      name: traefik-6f79c9bff5-ckfpn
      namespace: traefik
      ownerReferences:
        - *ref_12
      relationships:
        - *ref_13
        - *ref_14
        - *ref_15
      resourceVersion: '625722'
      state: *ref_16
      uid: a07d7f2b-145c-44bd-9db7-fbeb68ff826c
__clone: true
```